# How do you change the text of a button in Android to a String that you have coded?

Tags: java, android, string, button, textview

I've created a program which generates operations and gives you options to select, one of which is the right answer to the operation presented. I'm trying to figure out how to apply the Strings that the program creates to buttons and text in the actual application.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
    public static double value, falsevalue1, falsevalue2, falsevalue3;
    public static int xy;
    public static int randomchoicea, randomchoiceb, randomchoicec;
    public static String optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD, operation;

    public static void randomOperation() {

        double x = (int)(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        if (x == 1) {
            int a = (int) getInt100to5000(); int b = (int) getInt100to5000();
            operation = a + " + " + b;
            value = a + b;
```

How would I go about applying the option Strings and operation String to their respective buttons and TextViews? I hope this is enough information to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get your Button and Textviews view by findViewById() then apply a function for it like using Button.setOnClickListener() for the click action and TextView.setText() for changing the text of that textview or applying your code result. There is [reference](https://www.studytonight.com/android/get-edittext-set-textview) for you to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add onCLick listeners to buttons where you set text to TextView in that way textView.setText().

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText(text);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what are you trying to achieve, in order to get it, you will need to create the 4 buttons you want to change texts to, and also the textviews that you will modify as well.
After that it's necessary to instantiate those elements, so you can access the view and modify it, this is ann example of what I'm trying to explain, imagine the optionA button is the one with the right answer, the way you get the values doesn't matter, you may keep it the way it is:

```
 //This are declarations
    String optionAString;
    double value;
    Button optionAButton;
    TextView example;
```

Those are not declarations, but instantiations:

```
//After calculating the values you can do this in onCreate() or OnCreateView, depending of where are you using it, activity, Fragment, etc:
optionAButton = findViewById(R.id.option_a_button);
example = findViewById(R.id.text_view_example);

//this if for converting the doubles to Strings, them show the values
optionAButton.setText(String.valueOf(value));
example.setText(String.valueOf(a));
```

After doing all this, all you have to do is to set listeners in your buttons and do something with it